# Javascript template file

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I have a number of templates in my html file like

```
<script id="id1" type="text/template">
  -----
</script>
<script id="tid2" type="text/template">
  -----
</script> -----
----------
```

This is working fine ,I need to know,is it possible to move these templates into an external file (javascript or some other type),because i need a large number of templates for my html file,so this will make large number of lines .Not easy  to debug or edit.

Comment: you can move each template into a separate html file

Comment: Then how to include this? Is it possible to include it into a javascript file?

Comment: after moving them to html page you can include the html page either by ajax or by jquery load function. Also this answer might be helpful, have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/15250208/2592042

Answer (score 0):

Move each script in a seperate html or jsp file (if you use) and include them in your pages as

```
<link rel="import" href="/path/scriptPage1.jsp"> or 
<c:import url="/path/scriptPage1.jsp"/>
```